# unable to render a path on a map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

```
const flightPath = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
        {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
                type: "LineString",
                coordinates: [
                    [-87.6862308732, 41.8372950615],
                    [-118.408500088, 34.1182277898]
                ]
            },
            properties: {}
        }
    ]
};
```

i have the above geojson that i'd like to render a path along a geomercator projection and it seems to be not rendering.

here is more related code

```
const projection: GeoProjection = geoMercator();
const path = geoPath().projection(projection);

mapSelection
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(flightPath.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path as any)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", "5px");
```

here is the related gist https://gist.github.com/fc373745/a88702de093f1306e6e02fef72fbf2e7

Comment: gist is good, but demo would be better

Comment: Are you sure you are using reactjs ?

Comment: what i did was i selectAll("path") which probably selected the other paths as well, which i should've does was select a class and attribute that classname to the appended path. this worked lol dumb mistake